# Python 3.x Key Detect. Print statement comes after key detect function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to detect key pressing in Python 3.x in Mac Terminal, and here is the code I have

```
import tty
import termios
import sys


def get_key():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch


def key_detect():
    print("Key detect: ", end="")
    print(get_key())


while True:
    key_detect()
```

I suppose it works like:

```
Key detect:
```

and wait until I press something, print result, and should be waiting for next time. Like this:

```
Key detect: a
Key detect:
```

But it went like this:

```
// A cursor flashes, but nothing has been printed
```

And when I pressed something:

```
Key detect: a
*cursor*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is written to stdout (which is what print()) does before it's flushed. This happens implicitly when print() ends with the standard newline, but when you provide a different end="" like this (and the string is short), the implicit flush doesn't happen.

You can flush stdout explicitly, and that fixes the problem:

```
def key_detect():
    print("Key detect: ", end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print(get_key())
```

Comment: Or on Python 3.3 and up, you can supply `flush=True` to the `print` function.